# How can I change the margins of quote environment?

Tags: lyx

I am writing a text with `LyX` in the `KOMA` Script document class and have set the following margins under Document->Settings->Page Margins

```
top: 2.5cm
bottom: 2.5cm
inner: 2.5cm
outer: 3cm
```

As I am bound to `MLA` (Modern Language Association) formatting rules, I am using biblatex-mla package and have already altered the quote environment to be in a smaller fontsize and singlespaced. You can see that in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{<mybib.bib>}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\quote\singlespace
\makeatother
\let\quoteOLD\quote
\def\quote{\quoteOLD\small}
```

However, the long quotes that I have set to be in `LyX`'s "quote" paragraph environment are indented on the right side, i.e. the right maring is not 2.5cm, but more. How can I change that behavior of the "quote" paragraph environment in `LyX` and have long quotes that are set to the "quote" environment to be set in the same right margins as the rest of the text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What about the left margin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write into the preamble of your document (`Document->Settings->Preamble`) a redefinition of the `quote` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewenvironment{quote}
  {\small\list{}{\rightmargin=2.5cm \leftmargin=2.5cm}%
   \item\relax}
  {\endlist}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{quote}
\blindtext
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

[image]